# add the pagination, KeyError: 'url

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm doing my first spider, I need to enter a specific category, enter the publications and get the required data and then go through the various pages of that category but I found the following error that I can not solve.

This error started when I had to add the pagination

Thanks for the help

**item.py**

import scrapy

```
class ReporteinmobiliarioItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    titulo = scrapy.Field()
    precio = scrapy.Field()

    pass
```

**spider.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose
from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from reporteInmobiliario.items import ReporteinmobiliarioItem
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
from scrapy import Request


class reporteInmobiliario(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'zonaprop'
    start_urls = ['https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html']

    def parse(self,response):
        for folow_url in response.css("h4.aviso-data-title>a::attr(href)").extract():
            url = response.urljoin(folow_url)
            yield Request(url,callback = self.populate_item)

    def populate_item(self,response):
        item_loader = ItemLoader(item=ReporteinmobiliarioItem(),response=response)
        item_loader.default_input_procesor = MapCompose(remove_tags)
        item_loader.add_css('titulo', 'div.card-title>h1::text')
        item_loader.add_css('precio', 'strong.venta::text')

        item_loader.add_value('url',response.url)
        yield item_loader.load.item()

    def pagination(self,response):
        next_page = response.css('h4.aviso-data-title>a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page in None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            return Request(next_page,callback=self.parse)
```

**log:**

```
> 2018-09-11 10:28:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started
> (bot: reporteInmobiliario) 2018-09-11 10:28:56 [scrapy.utils.log]
> INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel
> 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)],
> pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2,
> Platform Windows-2012ServerR2-6.3.9600-SP0 2018-09-11 10:28:56
> [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME':
> 'reporteInmobiliario', 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8',
> 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'reporteInmobiliario.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY':
> True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['reporteInmobiliario.spiders']} 2018-09-11
> 10:28:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
> ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats', 
> 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole', 
> 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats'] 2018-09-11 10:28:57
> [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
> ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2018-09-11
> 10:28:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
> ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware', 
> 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2018-09-11 10:28:57
> [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
> ['reporteInmobiliario.pipelines.JsonWriterPipeline'] 2018-09-11
> 10:28:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2018-09-11 10:28:57
> [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
> scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2018-09-11 10:28:57
> [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
> 127.0.0.1:6024 2018-09-11 10:28:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/robots.txt> (referer: None)
> 2018-09-11 10:28:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html>
> (referer: None) 2018-09-11 10:29:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG:
> Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/av-juan-de-garay-2800-parque-patricios-capital-43299554.html>
> (referer:
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html)
> 2018-09-11 10:29:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/escalada-1500-mataderos-capital-federal-31974593.html>
> (referer:
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html)
> 2018-09-11 10:29:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/excelente-esquina-42930524.html>
> (referer:
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html)
> 2018-09-11 10:29:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/local-palermo-43757972.html>
> (referer:
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html)
> 2018-09-11 10:29:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/lote-en-alquiler-gascon-50-1-2-cuadra-av-rivadavia-32629293.html>
> (referer:
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html)
> 2018-09-11 10:29:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/victor-martinez-1600-parque-chacabuco-capital-20515827.html>
> (referer:
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html)
> 2018-09-11 10:29:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/lote-2000-metros-en-liniers-oportunidad!-43312489.html>
> (referer:
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html)
> 2018-09-11 10:29:00 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error
> processing <GET
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/propiedades/av-juan-de-garay-2800-parque-patricios-capital-43299554.html>
> (referer:
> https://www.zonaprop.com.ar/terrenos-alquiler-capital-federal.html)
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py",
> line 102, in iter_errback
>     yield next(it)   File "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py",
> line 30, in process_spider_output
>     for x in result:   File "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py",
> line 339, in <genexpr>
>     return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())   File "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py",
> line 37, in <genexpr>
>     return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))   File "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py",
> line 58, in <genexpr>
>     return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))   File "D:\Repositorio_Local\reporteInmobiliario\reporteInmobiliario\spiders\spider.py",
> line 34, in populate_item
>     item_loader.add_value('url',response.url)   File "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\loader\__init__.py",
> line 77, in add_value
>     self._add_value(field_name, value)   File "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\loader\__init__.py",
> line 91, in _add_value
>     processed_value = self._process_input_value(field_name, value)   File
> "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\loader\__init__.py",
> line 148, in _process_input_value
>     proc = self.get_input_processor(field_name)   File "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\loader\__init__.py",
> line 137, in get_input_processor
>     self.default_input_processor)   File "c:\users\ssalvadeo\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\loader\__init__.py",
> line 154, in _get_item_field_attr
>     value = self.item.fields[field_name].get(key, default) KeyError: 'url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `value = self.item.fields[field_name].get(key, default) KeyError: 'url` means that you haven't defined the `url` field in your `item`.

Update as follows:

```
class ReporteinmobiliarioItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    titulo = scrapy.Field()
    precio = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()

    pass
```